# c++ compare function result

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have the following code that is exhibiting some very strange behavior. does anyone have any idea why.

```
#include <iostream>

long global = 20001;

double foo() {return global / 1000.0;}

int main(int,char**) {
  if (foo() == foo()) {
    std::cout << "true\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "false\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This should print true as the function returns the same result each time but instead prints false;

This is built using g++ on Solaris 10. 
I don't know that the OS matter, but I haven't had a chance to try it on a different os

Comment: Try this:
    flost epsilon = 0.001f;
    if ( foo() - foo() < epsilon) 
 ....

Comment: I compiled your code and received a response of 'true'. I am running Ubuntu 12.04, with gcc 4.6.3. It looks like the OS may matter.

Comment: I got 'true' on Fedora with g++

Comment: @Kevin With what compiler options?  (Same thing for Mahmut.)

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith2.html

Comment: extra info, sorry I didn't include it in the original question:
os solaris 10 on x86 processor
compiler: g++ 4.7.1 without any flags (g++ main.cpp; ./a.out)
I tested on linux and the problem doesn't occur, so it must be solaris specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OS probably doesn't matter, but the compiler and the
architecture do.  On an Intel, the usual convention is to return
a floating point value in a floating point register, which has
64 bits precision (rather than the 53 of a double).  And of
course, the compiler does the arithmetic directly into that
register, so you end up returning a value with 64 bits
precision.

Of course, when the compiler generates code to call a function,
it can't leave the value in a register, since the function might
use that register.  So it spills it to memory.  As a double with
56 bits.  The `==` operator compares this 56 bit value from the
first call with the 64 bit value from the second, and finds that
they aren't equal.

I might add that if the compiler inlines the functions, the problem will probably disappear.

All of which is perfectly legal according to the standard.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable, is there any way to make the comparison work without storing the variables locally? this is Code pulled from a much larger function where storing the values in locals isn't really an option

Comment: -ffloat-store seems to fix it by preventing the floating point comparison from happening on the register. Thanks, you sir are a genius

Answer (score 1):

Likely a problem with doubles not evaluating to exactly the same value all the time (essentially rounding errors).

If you were to change your function to return integers, you would probably have the expected behaviour.

Very similar to this question:
[Deals with comparing floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

long   global = 20001;
double epsilon = std::numeric_limits::epsilon<double>();

double foo() {return global / 1000.0;}

int main(int,char**) {
  if (foo() - foo() > epsilon) {
    std::cout << "true\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "false\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except that doubles _do_ evaluate to the same value every time.  The problem is a side effect of Intel's extended precision in the registers.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know that.  So it's an intel only problem?

Comment: Today, probably.  In the past, I think Motorola chips also used extended precision, and could thus display the same problem.

Comment: Also, if the compiler uses the SSE instructions for floating point, it shouldn't be a problem either.